# How to make a http request in a playground update function?

Tags: openapi, elm, openapi-generator

I want to make http requests from my elm program.
I use the openapi-generator https://eriktim.github.io/openapi-elm for the http requests:
https://github.com/eriktim/openapi-elm,
The only example I could find is this:
https://github.com/eriktim/openapi-elm/tree/master/example
There, a request has e.g. type `Api.Request Api.Data.PlanetList` and is converted with the send function: `(Result Http.Error a -> msg) -> Request a -> Cmd msg`.
The send function takes a function to convert the Request result to msg but but returns it wrapped in `Cmd`.
The update function has type
`update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )`
So as long as the request is made in the update function and the result is put in the return value the framework will get `msg` out of `Cmd`.

Now I want to make requests in my program, but I'm using [playground](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-playground/latest) `game` as my main function ([example](https://elm-lang.org/examples/keyboard)) where the update function is `update : Computer -> Model -> Model` so the "trick" from the example project is not applicable. How can I still get the values from my request call then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Http request is a piece of data for the runtime to execute. If the `Cmd` is not passed to the runtime through the main `update`, the actual http call will never happen.

This is why you cannot have side-effects in simple programs (`Playground`  and `Browser.sandbox`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what elm-playground is, but that's not the right starting point for a webapp such as you want to create, as it does not support Commands, such as Http requests.

You want to be using normal / standard Elm - see https://guide.elm-lang.org/install/elm.html and then you want to be building a `Program` based on `Browser.document` - https://guide.elm-lang.org/webapps/

Hope that gets you on your way